# Verifying that the set {0,1} is a field

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory

I have a set consisting of $0$ and $1$ with addition and multiplication  as operations. $$0+0=1+1=0,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+0=0+1=1$$ $$0 \cdot 0= 0\cdot 1=1\cdot 0=0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1 \cdot 1=1$$

Now I have to verify that it is a field. So the properties of a field is:

a) $a+b=b+a$ and $a\cdot b=b \cdot a$.

$1+0=0+1=1$ and $ 0\cdot 1=1\cdot 0=0$

b) $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$ and $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=a\cdot (b\cdot c)$.

?

c) $a(b+c)=ab+ac$

?

d) There are distinct real numbers $0$ and $1$ such that $a+0=a$ and $a\cdot1=a$ $\forall a$.

?

e) For each $a$ there is a real number $-a$ such that $a+(-a)=0$ , and if $a\ne 0$, there is a real number $1/a$ such that $a(1/a)=1$.

?

My question is how does the set fulfil b), c), d), and e)?

Comment: There is nothing to verify, except using the addition and multiplication table. So for d) $1+0=0$ and $0+0=0$, $1\cdot 0=0$ etc. directly follows from it.

Comment: But b)  and c) are about three elements.

Comment: Yes, but it works the same: $(1+1)+1=1+(1+1)$ follows from $1+1=0$ and $0+1=1=1+0$, so nothing new. Since $a,b,c$ can only be $0$ or $1$, it is all a trivial computation. Even better is e). We must have $a=1$ if $a\neq 0$. So the computation is $1(1/1)=1$. Well,...

Comment: @AlimTeacher This just means that you have to verify $8$ cases instead of $4$. Of course, technically you are not using a "table" (thoughv you could, in a way).